# How do you accept a List<E> or an array E[] into a REST endpoint?

Tags: java, arrays, json, rest, request

I want to have a generic bulk update call, where the client sends an array of objects for me to update. The body of the request would look like this:

**Request Body**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "noe",
    "phone": "1234"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "noea",
    "phone": "1235"
  }
]
```

I've looked around and it seems like most marshalling providers can handle this in the body of the request. I've tried taking it a few different ways:

**E[ ] or List< E > Parameters**

How can I open what stream it's trying to read from? Am I missing some annotation or have the wrong @Consumes annotation? I did a little searching and I couldn't find anything that describes the problem I'm having.

```
    @PUT
    @Consumes( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
    @Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
    @Path( "/multiedit" )
    public Response edit( E[] objects ) {

    }
```

Or

```
    @PUT
    @Consumes( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
    @Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
    @Path( "/mutliedit" )
    public Response edit( List<E> entities ) {

    }
```

Produces

```
javax.json.JsonException: Unable to detect charset due to Stream closed
root cause: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

**Wrapper class**

After that I tried packing the array into a wrapper class.

```
public class EntityList<E> implements Serializable {
    private List<E> entities;
}

@PUT
@Consumes( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
@Path( "/multiedit" )
public Response edit( EntityList<E> entities ) 
{

}
```

This causes a mapping exception with my mapper api, Johnzon Mapper.

```
org.apache.johnzon.mapper.MapperException: Unsupported [<list of objects here>] com.my.project.EntityList<E>
```

I just want to accept an array of objects. I see it done in a bunch of different questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899586/post-array-of-objects-to-rest-api) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593720/jersey-how-to-post-a-list-of-json-objects), but it doesn't work for me.

UPDATE:
I can get the first two options working if I do a non-generic version of it. If I subclass a generic version of it and try to override it, it will still die with the same exceptions as stated.

Comment: Did you configure a proper reader to do the object parsing?
I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31990540/unmarshal-json-to-java-pojo-in-jax-rs) thread can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah,  I believe you are missing the `@QueryParam` Annotation.

```
@PUT
@Consumes( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
@Path( "/multiedit" )
public Response edit( @QueryParam("entities") EntityList<E> entities ) 
{

}
```

Comment: QueryParam is for parameters on the URL, like so: /?name=bob.

Comment: I'm not sure how he's `PUT`ting his list but you can also build up a list as `@QueryParams`.  Regardless, maybe he should use `@UriInfo`?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `@RequestBody` link this :

```
@PUT
@Consumes( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
@Path( "/multiedit" )
public Response edit(@RequestBody EntityList<E> entities ) 
{


}
```

Comment: I think RequestBody is only for Spring if I'm not mistaken; we're not using Spring